# How to stop my character from over rotating with zRotation constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have a vehicle in a platformer game I'm working on that I want to be able to allow rotation so it can roll up hills and such. I want to limit my vehicle to 30 degrees rotation in the negative and positive direction.

The issue is when i have rotation enabled and roll off of a cliff or straight edge drop off, my vehicle flips over off the side and lands on its head. I've been searching for a way to limit the zRotation to a set number of degrees in  each direction.

I tried using the IK constraints part from this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129895/sprite-kit-inverse-kinematics-swift-2 in my update function, but it had no effect.

Then I found this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint/1519706-zrotation#declarations

that seems to be exactly what I need, but I can't quite figure out how to implement it. any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: When using `zRotation` property, make sure you assign a value in radians to it... If this isn't an issue, post the relevant code..

Comment: I don't know what code I need. I'm aware that zRotation is in radians, but IK constraints are in degrees. I'm more interested in finding out how to use the apple zRotation function that limits rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
  let thirtyDegrees = CGFloat(0.523599) // Convert degrees to rads.

  let rotationRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: -thirtyDegrees, upperLimit: thirtyDegrees)

  let rotationConstraint = SKConstraint.zRotation(rotationRange)

  let vehicle = SKSpriteNode()

  vehicle.constraints = [rotationConstraint]
```

Comment: I put this in my player class and it worked perfectly. Thank you!