# How to find direction (in radians or degrees) of a physics body

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a physics body that gets hit and rotates a lot. I want to limit the amount it can rotate (only 45 degrees in each direction or something) and I wanted to try to do that by applying torque if the direction goes past a certain point. I'm ok with the sprite wobbling back and forth (it's a bird).

I'm open to other suggestions on how to limit the rotation as well.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've already tried using zRotation (I printed it out and it was always 0.) I also tried using the vector but that gave me the direction the sprite was going.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for [SKConstraint zRotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint/1519706-zrotation)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to use zRotation before and had it print(player.zRotation) and it only ever printed 0. Do you know something else I could do or why zRotation is always 0? Thanks again.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that creates the sprite and the physics body.

Comment: I found this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853745/how-to-stop-my-character-from-over-rotating-with-zrotation-constraints?rq=1 and I'm really sorry for posting this without looking into the other answers here correctly - I must have thought it was something else, I did look pretty thoroughly. Just out of curiosity, though, what information would the code give you (so that I can supply that next time.)

Comment: You wrote zRotation is always 0. Your code would likely show why